# Set Django set Integer Field minimum to 1

Tags: django, django-models

How can I create an integer field for a model such that the minimum allowed integer is 1?  I noticed Django has a `PositiveIntegerField` [documented here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/fields/#positiveintegerfield) but it allows 0s.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Use validators:

```
from django.core.validators import MinValueValidator

class MyModel(models.Model):
    num = models.PositiveIntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1)])
```